# Dropping N/A in One Step

Tags: r

```
data<- read.csv("Spreadsheet.csv") 
data_complete <- data[!(data$pred_ranking=="N/A"),]%>%
data[!(data$precaution_score=="N/A"),]
```

I am trying to drop the N/A values for pred_ranking and precaution_score. I am not sure how to drop both of these in one step.

```
library(dplyr)
data<- read.csv("Spreadsheet.csv")
data_complete <- data %>%
      na_if("N/A") %>%
      filter(complete.cases(pred_ranking, precaution_score))

d4 <- data %>%
              group_by(conference, school)%>% 
  filter(conference %in% c( "SEC"))
  
graph2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(Preseason.Ranking,precaution_score, color=school)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~conference, ncol = 2) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=2)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=5)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
graph2
```

dput:
structure(list(school = c("Air Force", "Akron", "Alabama", "App State",
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "Arkansas State", "Army", "ASU", "Auburn ",
"Ball State", "Baylor", "Boise State", "Boston College", "Bowling Green State",
"Buffalo", "BYU", "California", "Central Michigan", "Charlotte"
), state = c("Colorado", "Ohio", "Alabama", "North Carolina",
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "New York", "Arizona", "Alabama",
"Indiana", "Texas", "Idaho", "Massachusetts", "Ohio", "New York",
"Utah", "California", "Michigan", "North Carolina"), conference = c("Mountain West",
"Mid American", "SEC", "Sun Belt", "PAC 12", "SEC", "Sun Belt",
"Independent", "PAC 12", "SEC", "Mid American", "Big 12", "Mountain West",
"ACC", "Mid American", "Mid American", "Independent", "PAC 12",
"Mid American", "Conference USA"), Season = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L,
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L,
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Preseason.Ranking = c(71L,
125L, 1L, 43L, 94L, 61L, 108L, 82L, 24L, 30L, 50L, 67L, 32L,
42L, 128L, 84L, 45L, 69L, 98L, 115L), Post.Season.Ranking = c(74L,
125L, 1L, 39L, 98L, 56L, 101L, 77L, 23L, 19L, 66L, 47L, 46L,
54L, 126L, 40L, 13L, 51L, 85L, 111L), Difference.in.Ranking = c(-3L,
0L, 0L, 4L, -4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 11L, -16L, 20L, -14L, -12L,
2L, 44L, 32L, 18L, 13L, 4L), precaution_score = c("N/A", "N/A",
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A",
"N/A", "N/A", "3", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")), row.names = c(NA,
20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: In your code, `d4` is the object filtered created whereas you are using `d2` in `ggplot`, which was not created..  Perhaps you want `ggplot(d4, ...`

Comment: `pred_ranking` is not there in your dput(). Can you check again and upload?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `"N/A"` to `NA` with `na_if` and then use `complete.cases` in `filter` to subset the rows

```
library(dplyr)
data_complete <- data %>%
      na_if("N/A") %>%
      filter(complete.cases(pred_ranking, precaution_score))
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : 
attempt to apply non-function

Comment: @BC100 that error is not clear as the code is based on the code you showed on your post

Comment: What would make the error clearer?

Comment: @BC100 Your error `app$vspace` is not clear to me as there is nothing in the code about `app`

Comment: Would the dput help? I added the complete code.

Comment: @BC100 Yes, the `dput(head(data, 20))` would be good

Comment: @BC100 Is it an issue of `d2` vs `d4`?

Comment: The dput has been updated. The error is arising in line the filter line.

Comment: I was able to run all lines up to filter without the error and all lines after without an error.

Comment: @BC100 If you want to remove the rows with either NA in the columns you can use `data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.x, "N/A"))) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%  filter(complete.cases(Preseason.Ranking, precaution_score))` which return only a single row as per the dput

Comment: @BC100 If it is only to remove rows where both columns have NA `data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.x, "N/A"))) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%  filter(!if_all(c(Preseason.Ranking, precaution_score), is.na))`

Comment: I am able to use the code to remove the rows, but get the same error if I use the code to remove rows and columns. I need to remove rows and columns to get rid of N/As though

Comment: @BC100 I guess part of the reason your code is not working is code use original data sometimes to filter, then d2 instead of d4.  So, it is kind of confusing whether the error is due to syntactical or logical